# Flash as3 Open a File Locally (with FlashPunk)

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, load

Okay, so at the moment I am making a game in as3 with the FlashPunk framework. I have managed to set up ogmo editor to work with it, and the results have been good! I intend to send the ogmo project to some friends, so that they can make some levels for my game themselves. But I have run into a problem. I wanted my friends to be able to test the levels they make, so I set about trying to find a simple open file dialog solution, Sp that they can select the generated XML file (.oel), and then load it in to the actual game. But I just couldn't find a solution! Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your game is web based, you have to use the FileReference class. If it's air based, you can use the File class. Like so:

**File Reference:**

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class FileReference_event_select extends Sprite {
        private var uploadURL:URLRequest;
        private var file:FileReference;

        public function FileReference_event_select() {
            uploadURL = new URLRequest();
            uploadURL.url = "http://www.[yourDomain].com/yourUploadHandlerScript.cfm";
            file = new FileReference();
            file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
            file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
            file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            file.browse();
        }

        private function selectHandler(event:Event):void {
            var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
            trace("selectHandler: name=" + file.name + " URL=" + uploadURL.url);
            file.upload(uploadURL);
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
            trace("progressHandler: name=" + file.name + " bytesLoaded=" + event.bytesLoaded + " bytesTotal=" + event.bytesTotal);
        }

        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("completeHandler: " + event);
        }
    }
}
```

**File:**

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.events.Event;

var sourceFile:File = File.documentsDirectory;
sourceFile = sourceFile.resolvePath("Apollo Test/test1.txt");
var destination:File = File.documentsDirectory;
destination = destination.resolvePath("Apollo Test/test2.txt");
```

Sources:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html

Comment: Also note that the file reference class absolutely requires the user to have a file dialog box presented to them for selecting, while with the File class you can simply select files and manipulate them without user permission, since the user accepts that by installing your application, they have installed an actual application and therefore there is the assumption that the application will have system access like any other native application.

Comment: Also note that the examples above are simply copied from the flash documentation and (especially the first example) may be quite bloated compared to what you actually need. The first example is really just trying to show you absolutely best practice + using useful portions of the class. Much if it could be stripped if you simply just want to select and load a file into memory. Note further that in the first example they're showing you how to upload the file to a server. If you just want to load it locally into memory, you simply use FileReference.load(). see docs for more nfo.